# Is it Possible to Use Azure Active Directory to authenticate an on-premise DB that uses Windows Authentication?

Tags: database, windows, azure, function

I am developing an Azure Function App (v3) in .NET Core 3.1. I have a service account that has access to all of the databases/tables that my application needs to hit, but I want to avoid using windows authentication/impersonation every time I want to make a call to the database. Is there a way to ensure that my Azure Function always runs as my service account? And if so, will this service account being logged in through Azure Active Directory suffice for bypassing windows authentication on my on-premise DB? I have a hybrid connection set up as well.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support Azure Active Directory Authentication. Reference here: [Choose an Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15):

During setup, you must select an authentication mode for the Database Engine. **There are two possible modes: Windows Authentication mode and mixed mode. Windows Authentication mode enables Windows Authentication and disables SQL Server Authentication. Mixed mode enables both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication.** Windows Authentication is always available and cannot be disabled.

[Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) is a mechanism of connecting to Azure SQL Database, Managed Instance, and SQL Data Warehouse by using identities in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

It's  impossible to Use Azure Active Directory to authenticate an on-premise DB that uses Windows Authentication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to run an Azure Function as a Windows Auth user?  That way requests to the on-prem DB will use that Windows Auth credentials (and it will be given access)?